# Trouble parsing € with Barcode4J MessagePatternUtil

Tags: unicode, barcode4j

I'm trying to insert a € in the Message and/or Pattern for a barcode using
`org.krysalis.barcode4j.tools.MessagePatternUtil`

in Barcode4J, but am just getting hieroglyphics.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems MessagePatternUtil works on a byte-by-byte basis, so it can't handle multiple-byte characters like the € (Euro).

I've posted an improved version that can handle Unicode here:
https://github.com/DanskerDave/barcode4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/krysalis/barcode4j/tools/MessagePatternUtil.java